# Multiple recursive async_wait on boost asio steady_timer

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

This question is inspired by the tutorial on asynchronous timer from boost asio documentation ([link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer3.html)). The code is slightly modified to make the effect more obvious.

There is a related question, [Multiple async_wait from a boost Asio deadline_timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085565/multiple-async-wait-from-a-boost-asio-deadline-timer). But I am not sure if the answer in that question applies to my case.

The code is pretty simple and works as expected if the duplicated line is commented out, as shown below.

1. A `steady_timer` with a duration of `1s` calls `async_wait`.
2. When it expires, the handler is called. Inside the handler, the lifetime of the timer is extended by one more second, and the timer calls `async_wait` again.
3. Variable `count` of 20 is used to limit number of times the timer can fire off.

---

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;

void bind_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec,
                  asio::steady_timer& t,
                  int count) {
  if (count > 0) {
    std::cout << "getting " << count << "\n";
    t.expires_at(t.expiry() + std::chrono::seconds(1));
    t.async_wait(boost::bind(bind_handler, asio::placeholders::error,
                             boost::ref(t), --count));
  }
}

int main() {
  asio::io_context io_context(1);
  asio::steady_timer t(io_context, std::chrono::seconds(1));

  int count = 20;

  t.async_wait(boost::bind(bind_handler, asio::placeholders::error,
                           boost::ref(t), count));
  //t.async_wait(boost::bind(bind_handler, asio::placeholders::error,
  //                         boost::ref(t), count));

  auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  io_context.run();
  auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  std::cout
      << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - start).count()
      << " seconds passed\n";

  return 0;
}
```

---

The output of this code is shown below. A new line is printed with each second that passes.

```
getting 20
getting 19
getting 18
...lines...
...omitted...
getting 3
getting 2
getting 1
21 seconds passed
```

However, if two lines in the code above are uncommented, the program behaves very differently. The output is pasted below. The program prints all lines from `getting 20` to `getting 1` within a second, shows nothing for 40 seconds and then prints the last line.

```
getting 20
getting 20
getting 19
getting 19
getting 18
getting 18
...lines...
...omitted...
getting 3
getting 3
getting 2
getting 2
getting 1
getting 1
41 seconds passed
```

My question is, how does multiple recursive call of `async_wait` affect the behavior of the program? I feel some kind of data race is going on, but the numbers are still printed sequentially. Besides, only a single thread is involved, as we can see in `io_context` constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like the answer for the behavior lies in the documentation for [`basic_waitable_timer::expires_at(const time_point & expiry_time)`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer/expires_at/overload2.html):

> This function sets the expiry time. Any pending asynchronous wait operations will be cancelled. The handler for each cancelled operation will be invoked with the boost::asio::error::operation_aborted error code.

In your example, when the first timer finishes, it calls `expires_at` in order to forward the timer a second. However this cancels the second running await call, which now will be called directly in the next eventloop iteration with an `operation_aborted` error. However since you don't check the error code `ec`, you don't see that. Now this handler will directly forward the timer again, and thereby cancel the last `async_wait` that had been started.

This goes on, until the handlers cancelled themselves often enough that `count==0` and only a single timer is running. Since the expiry date has been forwarded each time by 1s, the code still waits for the full 40s to elapse.

Comment: I think you are right. I added a error check at handler, and it did show `operation_aborted` error. But I haven't understand every detail yet. I'll accept your answer when I fully understand it.

Comment: "In your example, when the second timer finishes, it calls expires_at in order to forward the timer a second." Why would the second timer finish and cancels the first running await call, instead of the other way around? For example, first timers finishes, calls `expires_at`, cancels second await call.

Comment: You are right, it's the first timer elapsing that initiates the sequence. I updated the answer.

Comment: It's very strange. I did another test. It's actually the second timer canceling events from first timer. I have create a gist for my test. https://gist.github.com/mywtfmp3/ff64371a6e82930ee2f355a7a9e96965. However, this sounds like another question. Do you prefer me to accept the answer here and open another question?

Comment: It sounds like another question, since the root cause of the original issue (why is everything printed at once) has been identified.

Comment: I am always forgetting to check boost's ec codes for error at the top of handlers.  It's just something you have to remember.